# convergence in probability (MLE)

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Can someone please explain what the following phrase actually implies:
  $\mathbf{\hat{θ}}$ converges to $\mathbf{θ}$ in probability with order $\mathbf{\hat{θ}}−\mathbf{θ}=O_p (n^{-\frac{1}{2}})$  ?
 ($\mathbf{\hat{θ}}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator)

Comment: See the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation#Big_O:_stochastic_boundedness): for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M>0$ such that $P(\sqrt{n}|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| > M) < \epsilon$ for all large $n$. (Thanks kimchi lover for the correction.)

Comment: @angryavian : There's still the matter of the meaning of $O_p(n^{-1/2}). \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a sequence of random variables $X_n$ (such as your $\hat \theta_n-\theta$) to be $O_P(1)$ means it is tight: for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a compact  set $K$ such that $P(X_n\in K)>1-\epsilon)$ for all $n$.  To say $X_n=O_P(1/\sqrt n)$ is to say that $\sqrt n X_n = O_P(1)$.  One way this can happen is if $\sqrt n X_n$ converges in distribution (in a statistics context, probably to a gaussian limit) but it can happen that one subsequence of $\sqrt n X_n$ has one distributional limit and another subsequence has another.

*Stochastically bounded* or *bounded in probability*  are alternative terms for $O_P(1)$. The notation seems to be due to Mann and Wald in 1943; see [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4612-5254-2%2F1.pdf) for more on this topic.